# Xubuntu 14.04.1 Freezes Using Firefox

Tags: xubuntu

Using an eMachines ET1331G-03w. The first thing I do on a new install is get Google Chrome. Every time I attempt to visit google.com/chrome, the screen does this crazy thing and the system becomes unusable. What are the possible causes? I haven't tried installing regular Ubuntu yet.

Comment: What are the results of running the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices` to identify a possible missing NVIDIA graphics driver?

Comment: phm@LuckyCompCo:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000003D0sv00001025sd00000181bc03sc00i00
model    : C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-173 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free

Comment: I finished installing updates and then tried visiting google.com/chrome again. This time it briefly froze only inside the Firefox window, but then the whole screen went on to freeze within about 10 seconds. On a previous attempt to install, I changed these drivers with no good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` tells you to install the nvidia-304-updates recommended graphics driver for your NVIDIA GPU. If you haven't already installed nvidia-304-updates, the way to install it from the terminal is:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304-updates  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It actually is the onboard, so I'm hoping that installing updates works. Anything else to try if that doesn't work?

Comment: Installing the updates worked. Currently on Xubuntu, in Chrome, adding this comment. Thanks!

Comment: I am SO HAPPY that installing the updates worked because buying a new discrete graphics card for an old computer can be a real hassle, and worse than that sometimes it solves nothing, in case your freezing problem was caused by a different hardware issue.

Comment: Though, the specs on this machine might surprise you: http://www.engadget.com/products/emachines/et1331g-03w/specs/